# Aggregate Issue list from multiple builds in TeamCity

Tags: jira, teamcity

I have a TeamCity server building our deployments which is linked in with our issue trackers (both JIRA and TeamCity). If I put the right tag on the check-in comment this automatically links the build to an issue in the tracker and I can see a list of issues resolved in this build.

I'd like to aggregate this list of Issues across multiple builds. Basically, I'd like to automatically generate documentation for releases, which might comprise multiple builds. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: This is about using/working with a development tool, making it [off-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) on [SF].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue tracker in teamcity only shows you the relevant tickets in a build. If you know the build number from where to start you can filter the list starting from that build to get an aggregate list.

Alternatively you can use a third-party tool that does something similar. Not sure what version control system you are using but we are using [GitReleaseNotes](https://github.com/JakeGinnivan/GitReleaseNotes) to extract tickets from commits and link to Jira.